# S4Hana(ERP) backend does not return localized error message due to additional ‘sap-language’ header is being added by the Cloud SDK

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

*Note: Application is built in CAP Java Stack along with DWC framework. Technical user is configurated in destination service for making an API call.*

**Flow :**

- API call gets initiated from UI.
- The application layer receives the
  request and respond with 204
- Then starts the async process
  explicitly via spring events and adds custom header as ‘sap-language’
  based on user's locale before making the call to S4 backend.

```
httpHeaders.put(DefaultErpHttpDestination.LOCALE_HEADER_NAME, dwcHeaderContainer.getHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE)); 

ModificationResponse<PurchaseRequisition> s4ReqResponse = 
s4opRequistionService.createPurchaseRequisition(s4opRequistion).withHeaders(httpHeaders).executeRequest(destinationProvider.getDestination());
```

However, Observed the underlying cloud SDK layer which 1st makes the call to destination service and retrieves the provided headers and then gets system current locale based on some constraint and adds a header again for ‘**sap-language**’ with the default system locale as 'en' which leads to problem in our case.

**Calling stack trace :**

```
Thread [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-60] (Suspended) 
CdsRequestHeaderFacade.tryGetRequestHeaders() line: 28  
RequestHeaderAccessor.tryGetHeaderContainer() line: 89  
DefaultLocaleFacade.getLocalesByHeaders() line: 48  
DefaultLocaleFacade.getCurrentLocales() line: 36    
DefaultLocaleFacade(LocaleFacade).getCurrentLocale() line: 27   
LocaleAccessor.getCurrentLocale() line: 53  
371621826.get() line: not available 
Option$None<T>(Option<T>).getOrElse(Supplier<? extends T>) line: 336    
DefaultErpHttpDestination(ErpHttpDestinationProperties).getLocale() line: 51    
DefaultErpHttpDestination.getHeadersToAdd() line: 188   
DefaultErpHttpDestination.getHeaders(URI) line: 169 
HttpClientWrapper.wrapRequest(HttpUriRequest) line: 98  
HttpClientWrapper.execute(HttpUriRequest) line: 116 
HttpClientWrapper.execute(HttpUriRequest) line: 35  
DefaultCsrfTokenRetriever.retrieveCsrfTokenResponseHeader(HttpClient, String, Map<String,String>) line: 91  
DefaultCsrfTokenRetriever.retrieveCsrfToken(HttpClient, String, Map<String,String>) line: 54    
ODataRequestCreate(ODataRequestGeneric).lambda$tryGetCsrfToken$5ab307ff$1(CsrfTokenRetriever, HttpClient) line: 266 
659039215.apply() line: not available   
Try<T>.of(CheckedFunction0<? extends T>) line: 75   
ODataRequestCreate(ODataRequestGeneric).tryGetCsrfToken(HttpClient, CsrfTokenRetriever) line: 266   
ODataRequestCreate(ODataRequestGeneric).tryExecuteWithCsrfToken(HttpClient, Supplier<HttpResponse>) line: 239   
ODataRequestCreate.execute(HttpClient) line: 93 
PurchaseRequisitionCreateFluentHelper(FluentHelperCreate<FluentHelperT,EntityT>).executeRequest(HttpDestinationProperties) line: 246    
xxxxxx.copyPR(Map<String,Object>) line: 176 
xxxxxx.s4AdapterResponseToxxxxxx(xxxxxx) line: 69   
xxxxxx.onApplicationEvent(xxxxxx) line: 58  
xxxxxxSpringListener.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent) line: 1   
SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(ApplicationListener, ApplicationEvent)   
SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(ApplicationListener<?>, ApplicationEvent)
SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.lambda$multicastEvent$0(ApplicationListener, ApplicationEvent)    
1824178544.run() line: not available    
DwcContextTaskDecorator.lambda$decorate$0(Map, Runnable) line: 33   
1126784716.run() line: not available    
Thread.run() line: 829
```

**Sample Http Out Going request and response looks like :**

```
http-outgoing-13 >> "POST /sap/opu/odata/sap/API_PURCHASEREQ_PROCESS_SRV/A_PurchaseRequisitionHeader HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 >> "sap-language: de[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 >> "Accept: application/json[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 >> "RequestID: xxxxx[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 >> "RepeatabilityCreation: 2022-09-19T08:50:00.889315900Z[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 >> "X-CorrelationID: [\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 >> "x-csrf-token: xxxxx==[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 >> "Content-Type: application/json[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 >> "Authorization: Basic XXXX[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 >> "sap-language: en[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 >> "Content-Length: 1383[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 >> "Host: XXXX[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 >> "Connection: Keep-Alive[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 >> "User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.13 (Java/11.0.16)[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 >> "Cookie: XXX%3d; sap-usercontext=sap-language=en&sap-client=xxx[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 >> "[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 >> "body_xxx"
http-outgoing-13 << "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request[\r][\n]"
http-outgoing-13 << {"error":{"code":"06/101","message":{"lang":"en","value":"No master record exists for supplier EPRINT"}"}
```

If you notice, there are two '**sap-language**' header goes to backend as mentioned above and S4 backend layer considers the last header attribute and returns  the error message always in English. Our expectation is error messages should come based on user’s locale…

**Following queries :**

**Is there any way by which application layer can instruct to Cloud SDK like Not to append again 'sap-language' header and give preference to what is being passed by the custom header as ‘sap-language’ As ‘de’ in our case?**

**Is it the bug from Cloud SDK?**

Any recommendation or inputs to address this issue..

Answer (score 0):

### Answers

> Is it the bug from Cloud SDK?

Not really, to me this looks like an incorrect API usage:

Your Destination is of type `DefaultErpHttpDestination`. It is significantly different from regular destination types, because **it automatically adds headers `sap-client` and `sap-language`**. It seems like the class cannot resolve the request headers at runtime, therefore falls back to system default `en`.

You are adding headers via OData API, while technically possible it's unreasonable for your actual call. As it results in duplicate header entry.

---

> Is there any way for Cloud SDK not to append again 'sap-language' header?

Yes, do not cast to `ErpHttpDestination` explicitly.

---

### Recommendation

Instead of fiddling with the destination or odata request, I would suggest to use the following code:

```
ModificationResponse<PurchaseRequisition> s4ReqResponse =
  RequestHeaderAccessor.executeWithHeaderContainer(
    dwcHeaderContainer.getHeaders(), 
    () -> s4opRequistionService
      .createPurchaseRequisition(s4opRequistion)
      .executeRequest(destinationProvider.getDestination()));
```

Reason:

- Keep benefits of `ErpHttpDestination`
- Enable correct locale resolution by leveraging the request headers and establishing a `ThreadContext`.

Comment: tried the above recommendation. However, it did not work. Still getting the same problem. ‘sap-language’ header is still not being populated with user's locale even we are supplying via dwcHeaderContainer.getHeaders() in executeWithHeaderContainer() method. 
I have provided detail analysis as an answer below. Comment has char’s restriction in stackoverflow . 
Could you plz check once and suggest if i missing something or anything w.r.t version which needs to be upgraded in order to adopt the recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

@Alexander, Tried with the following code, however did not work as expected.

**Could you plz check once and suggest if i am missing something or anything w.r.t version which needs to be upgraded in order to adopt the recommendation**

```
ModificationResponse<PurchaseRequisition> s4ReqResponse =
          RequestHeaderAccessor.executeWithHeaderContainer(dwcHeaderContainer.getHeaders(), () -> {
            ModificationResponse<PurchaseRequisition> s4Response = null;¬
            try {
              s4Response = s4opRequistionService.createPurchaseRequisition(s4opRequistion)
                  .executeRequest(destinationProvider.getDestination());
              return s4Response;
            } catch (ODataException e) {
              logger.error(EXCEPTION_FROM_COPYPR);
              logAndSendErrorMessageToCore(e, requisition);
            }
            return s4Response;
          }
          );
```

- Also ensured dwcHeaderContainer consists the values as such {accept-language=de} along with few other attributes.
- Still stack trace looks similar and could not found a place underneath where it picks the header value from the supplied header values via RequestHeaderAccessor. executeWithHeaderContainer()

**StackTrace**:

```
Thread [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-41] (Suspended) 
CdsRequestHeaderFacade.tryGetRequestHeaders() line: 28  
RequestHeaderAccessor.tryGetHeaderContainer() line: 89  
DefaultLocaleFacade.getLocalesByHeaders() line: 48  
DefaultLocaleFacade.getCurrentLocales() line: 36    
DefaultLocaleFacade(LocaleFacade).getCurrentLocale() line: 27   
LocaleAccessor.getCurrentLocale() line: 53  
2065479632.get() line: not available    
Option$None<T>(Option<T>).getOrElse(Supplier<? extends T>) line: 336    
DefaultErpHttpDestination(ErpHttpDestinationProperties).getLocale() line: 51    
DefaultErpHttpDestination.getHeadersToAdd() line: 188   
DefaultErpHttpDestination.getHeaders(URI) line: 169 
HttpClientWrapper.wrapRequest(HttpUriRequest) line: 98  
HttpClientWrapper.execute(HttpUriRequest) line: 116 
HttpClientWrapper.execute(HttpUriRequest) line: 35  
DefaultCsrfTokenRetriever.retrieveCsrfTokenResponseHeader(HttpClient, String, Map<String,String>) line: 91  
DefaultCsrfTokenRetriever.retrieveCsrfToken(HttpClient, String, Map<String,String>) line: 54    
ODataRequestCreate(ODataRequestGeneric).lambda$tryGetCsrfToken$5ab307ff$1(CsrfTokenRetriever, HttpClient) line: 266 
1607932978.apply() line: not available  
Try<T>.of(CheckedFunction0<? extends T>) line: 75   
ODataRequestCreate(ODataRequestGeneric).tryGetCsrfToken(HttpClient, CsrfTokenRetriever) line: 266   
ODataRequestCreate(ODataRequestGeneric).tryExecuteWithCsrfToken(HttpClient, Supplier<HttpResponse>) line: 239   
ODataRequestCreate.execute(HttpClient) line: 93 
PurchaseRequisitionCreateFluentHelper(FluentHelperCreate<FluentHelperT,EntityT>).executeRequest(HttpDestinationProperties) line: 246    
S4Adapter.lambda$0(PurchaseRequisition, Map) line: 177  
64962500.call() line: not available 
ThreadContextCallable<T>.call() line: 229   
ThreadContextExecutor(AbstractThreadContextExecutor<ExecutorT>).execute(Callable<T>) line: 320  
RequestHeaderAccessor.executeWithHeaderContainer(RequestHeaderContainer, Callable<T>) line: 185 
RequestHeaderAccessor.executeWithHeaderContainer(Map<String,String>, Callable<T>) line: 160 
S4Adapter.copyPR(Map<String,Object>) line: 173
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you're using CAP/CDS from the stacktrace. This makes my previous recommendation obsolete. Do you have a `CdsRuntime` instance in this code available at runtime?

Comment: Did some further analysis, this problem is only happening in async approach. 
For the sync flow, it derives the ‘sap-langauage’ from the http request based on accept-language and works as expected.
As per design we have **Async flow** where this problem exist, looks like problem is happening : CdsRequestHeaderFacade.java
Map<String, String> headers RequestContext.getCurrent(runtime).getParameterInfo().getHeaders();
 the above lines always returns as empty headers for async flow even when we call either this RequestHeaderAccessor.executeWithHeaderContainer or old existing code.

Comment: At the moment `executeWithHeaderContainer` method from Cloud SDK is incompatible with `CdsRuntime` derived information from CAP. Hence I'm suggesting to enable the following snippet in your **async** case first: `RequestContext.getCurrent(runtime).getParameterInfo().getHeaders()`. As soon as this works and returns non-empty, then the destination resolution will work out of the box as well - similar to the **sync** case. If you think this is too much hassle, then you could go with the removal of `ErpHttpDestination` cast. Depends on your code quality / available capacity.

Comment: The underlying cloud SDK invokes **CdsRequestHeaderFacade** to get the header properties and **RequestContext.getCurrent(runtime)** always used to create a new cdsRuntime in our case.
Now added below code so that it will return the existing context with updated header attributes as well, now explicitly setting the paramInfo from dwcHeader with ACCEPT_LANGUAGE header so that underlying cloud SDK when it invokes the CdsRequestHeaderFacade, it returns the supplied header as well from the existing cdsRuntime... Code snippet added as another comment .. plz see below

Comment: Code snippet, **after this fix the flow is working as expected for the async flow **  
`cdsRuntime.requestContext().run(context -> {
ModifiableParameterInfo paramInfo = (ModifiableParameterInfo) RequestContext.getCurrent(cdsRuntime).getParameterInfo();
paramInfo.setHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE, dwcHeaderContainer.getHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE));
ModificationResponse<PurchaseRequisition> response = s4ReqSrv.createPurchaseRequisition(s4opRequistion)
 .withHeaders(httpHeaders).executeRequest(destinationProvider.getDestination());                    
          });   `

Comment: @Alexander, Hoping executeWithHeaderContainer method from Cloud SDK will be compatible with CdsRuntime or dwcHeaderContainer in future.  Thanks for your support.

Comment: "Compatible in the future" - yes it will be. We are working on it starting in Q4/2022, but we already came to the conclusion: this feature is surprisingly complex when considering other libraries as well. I'm happy the workaround above works for you, however I would've hoped it was easier with CdsRuntime in async mode. Maybe it would be good to also ask CAP/CDS colleagues whether this API call really is the easiest way to pass on runtime related headers.